# Eclipse CDT with existing C/C++ projects

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to use Eclipse for C/C++ developers version with MinGW to build my IDE.

The first thing I want to try is to import my existing C project.

However after I importing the codes I found several problems I cannot handle

1. It cannot resolve the includes, e.g. in a.c I am using macros defined in c.h, but a.c doesn't include c.h directly, it `#include "path/to/b.h"` and in b.h, it `#include "c.h"`. I tried to add the directory path of b.h and c.h to the includes option, but it does not work.
2. It cannot use macros defined in the Makefile, how can I make it aware of the -D, -I options set in the Makefile?

Comment: You can set this stuff in `C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols` of your project properties.

Comment: Thanks, is there any automatic way of importing the definitions in the Makefile?

Comment: I'm afraid no, at least not I know about. But for building you can specify to use your original one, instead of an Eclipse generated.

Comment: Thanks again. One more question, I found the "automatically generate Makefiles" option is grey (disabled), why is that happening?

Comment: Usually imported projects are considered to have their makefiles already. You can control the project type to chose when importing from source files IIRC.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please put your comment in an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set general include paths and `#define` symbols to be used by the indexer in the project properties `C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols` pages.

There's no automatic way I know to import these settings from a makefile AFAIK.